# Maxima and Jupyter - will Homebrew work?

Tags: macos, homebrew, python, open-source

I'd like to give [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/) a try in a [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/) notebook on my Mac.  Is the [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) version of Maxima up to the task?

I did try following the instructions at https://github.com/robert-dodier/maxima-jupyter , but I immediately got a non-informative error:

```
% curl -L -O https://github.com/robert-dodier/maxima-jupyter/archive/master.zip
% unzip master.zip && cd maxima-jupyter-master
% rlwrap maxima
Maxima 5.43.2 http://maxima.sourceforge.net
using Lisp SBCL 2.0.0
Distributed under the GNU Public License. See the file COPYING.
Dedicated to the memory of William Schelter.
The function bug_report() provides bug reporting information.
(%i1) load("load-maxima-jupyter.lisp");
; 
; compilation unit aborted
;   caught 1 fatal ERROR condition

loadfile: failed to load load-maxima-jupyter.lisp
 -- an error. To debug this try: debugmode(true);
(%i2)
```

I installed both `maxima` and `jupyter` via `brew`, here are their versions:

```
% maxima --version
Maxima 5.43.2

% jupyter --version
jupyter core     : 4.6.3
jupyter-notebook : 6.0.3
qtconsole        : 4.7.3
ipython          : 7.13.0
ipykernel        : 5.2.1
jupyter client   : 6.1.3
jupyter lab      : not installed
nbconvert        : 5.6.1
ipywidgets       : 7.5.1
nbformat         : 5.0.6
traitlets        : 4.3.3
```

Any advice?

Comment: What happens if you `brew install maxima`? Does it do what you expect?

Comment: @synoli This is using the `brew`-installed Maxima, I'll make that more clear in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully installed Maxima-Jupyter on macOS using Homebrew.

```
brew uninstall maxima # (if you have already installed)
brew install sbcl gpg zmq gnuplot
brew edit maxima
```

Edit Formula/maxima.rb. Comment out "--enable-sbcl-exec",

```
                          "--enable-sbcl",
#                         "--enable-sbcl-exec",
```

Save and quit

```
brew install maxima -s # you need -s to compile from source
```

Assuming you have [quicklisp](https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/) installed successfully,

```
unzip maxima-jupyter-master.zip
cd maxima-jupyter-master
maxima
(%i1) load("load-maxima-jupyter.lisp");
(%i2) jupyter_install();
(%i3) quit();
```